# Async run copy files task in pyside2

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm making a ui program to copy files.
And I put some button to control it like this.

[image]

I use a thread and asyncio to get path from a txt and then copy files.

```
class CopyThread(QThread):

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.running = True
        asyncio.run(self.main_process(unix_local_path, unix_remote_path))

    async def main_process(self, local_path, remote_path):

        async with aiofiles.open(PATH_LIST_FILE,
                'r+',
                encoding='utf-8') as file_list_io:
            async for line in file_list_io:
                if len(line.strip()) != 0:
                    remote_file_path= line
                    local_file_path = remote_file_path.replace(
                        remote_path, local_path)
                    assert self.running
                    await aioshutil.copy2(local_file_path, remote_file_path)

    self.running = False
```

Is it a correct way to do this? I feel it seems slower than multithreading. But if I use multithreading, I don't know how to pause it correctly. Any idea can be helpful. And sorry for my poor syntax.

Comment: That code doesn't seem to do the copying in parallel. In fact, I don't really see the point of all the async complications. What does that really achieve? To optimise performance, a shared queue with multiple worker threads would seem adequate. You can use signals to update progress in the main thread. To support pausing, you'd need to copy the files in smallish chunks. That would allow you to poll a flag between writes.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your advice.  But I still got problem about asyncio. Can it work for this task? By the way, I don't know how to copy the files in smallish chunks. Is it like `with open(local_file_path, 'rb') as r: with open(remote_file_path, 'wb') as w: while r.read(200): w.write(200)` ?